# What's the best technique for handling US Dollar calculations in Perl?

Tags: perl, currency, decimal-point

What's the best technique for handling US Dollar calculations in Perl?

Especially: the following needs to work:

```
$balance = 10;
$payment = $balance / 3; # Each payment should be 3.33. How best to round amount?
$balance -= $payment * 3;
# assert: $balance == .01
```

Comment: What should `$payment` be if `$balance` is 5?

Comment: Good point. My answer: up to the client to tell me how to round (up or down) payments to the nearest cent. In this specific case I'd like to round down to be sure to not overcharge.

Comment: @Larry K, in that case, use [Greg Hewgill's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269133/perl-technique-for-money-calculations/1269182#1269182)

Comment: I've re-thought my comment above. My plan has always been to calculate the first payment to be the remainder--the first payment would be slightly larger if needed. I now realize that the first payment could also be slightly smaller due to the other payments being rounded up. Thanks for your comments and answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [Math::Currency](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Math::Currency).

**Updated:**

Assuming all payments adding up to the balance is desirable, I came up with the following script based on [the points made by Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269133/perl-technique-for-money-calculations/1269182#1269182):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw( sum );

my @balances = (10, 1, .50, 5, 7, 12, 3, 2, 8, 1012);

for my $balance (@balances) {
    my @stream = get_payment_stream($balance, 3);
    my $sum = sum @stream;
    print "$balance : @stream : $sum\n";
}

sub get_payment_stream {
    my ($balance, $installments) = @_;
    $balance *= 100;
    my $payment = int($balance / $installments);
    $installments -= 1;
    my $residual = $balance - int($payment * $installments);
    my @stream = (($payment) x $installments, $residual);
    return map { sprintf '%.2f', $_ / 100} @stream;
}
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Temp> p
10 : 3.33 3.33 3.34 : 10
1 : 0.33 0.33 0.34 : 1
0.5 : 0.16 0.16 0.18 : 0.5
5 : 1.66 1.66 1.68 : 5
7 : 2.33 2.33 2.34 : 7
12 : 4.00 4.00 4.00 : 12
3 : 1.00 1.00 1.00 : 3
2 : 0.66 0.66 0.68 : 2
8 : 2.66 2.66 2.68 : 8
1012 : 337.33 337.33 337.34 : 1012
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll go with Math::Currency.

Answer (score 10):

One common technique is to do all calculations in *integer cents*, then convert to dollars and cents for output. So your $10 balance would be represented by 1000 (cents), and dividing by three gives 333, or $3.33.

However, if you want to divide a $10 payment by three, you will need some way to end up with payments of $3.33, $3.33, and **$3.34**. This will be more up to your application logic and business rules than the arithmetic features of your language.

Comment: One good thing would be also to hash out the details either with the lawyers (if it's one's own company) - so the proper user-facing agreements carry this in the small letters; or to ensure these details are very clearly spelled out in the product requirement documents if this is a contracting work. Making assumptions in this area is dangerous. For some strange reason people tend to be sensitive about it.

Comment: +1 Yes, in the past, I've used this technique. I wanted to see if there's something better these days. Math::Currency looks good.

Answer (score 0):

use Math::Currency;

Not reinventing the wheel is a good thing :)